# Selenium getAttribute(href) return null value using java - Salesforce application

Tags: java, selenium, salesforce-lightning

This is the salesforce application.
I want to get the below attributes value from the `<a>` tag

1. Href
2. Title

HTML Code

```
<one-app-nav-bar-item-root one-appnavbar_appnavbar="" data-id="home" data-assistive-id="operationId" aria-hidden="false" draggable="true" class="navItem slds-context-bar__item slds-shrink-none slds-is-active" role="listitem" xpath="1">
<a href="/lightning/page/home" title="Home" tabindex="0" draggable="false" aria-describedby="operationId-14" class="slds-context-bar__label-action dndItem" style="">
<span class="slds-truncate">Home</span>
</a></one-app-nav-bar-item-root>
```

Selenium code (groovy scripting language)

```
for(int i:(1..size)){
            WebElement getHref = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//one-app-nav-bar-item-root[${i}]//a[1]"))
            println getHref.getAttribute("href")
            println getHref.getAttribute("title")
}
```

output

```
null
null
```

NOTE:
When I execute the above code in FireFox, I'm getting my expected result

Comment: Strange syntax for Java.

Comment: Is it possible to share url?

Answer (score 0):

To extract the value of `href` and `title` attributes you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` or `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *xpath*:

  - `href`:

    ```
    System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//one-app-nav-bar-item-root/a[//span[text()='Home']]"))).getAttribute("href"));
    ```
  - `title`:

    ```
    System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//one-app-nav-bar-item-root/a[//span[text()='Home']]"))).getAttribute("title"));
    ```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but it's not working. getting again null

Comment: @Prabu Can you check the HTML if this element is within any iframe?

Comment: no iframe, when I use the getText() method with the same XPath got the value, but when I use getAttribute() getting null

Comment: @Prabu Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of xpath like `//one-app-nav-bar-item-root[${i}]//a[1]`

Try like `(//*[@role='listitem'])[${i}]//a[1]`

Comment: Can you just print and see if the links are available in the DOM by using the for loop on  //a  ?

Comment: yes I verified, and all the element loaded properly in the DOM